# How to close this pure css popup with anywhere or outside click?

Tags: html, css

Here is the HTML Code, check out this fiddle for full working code - 
https://jsfiddle.net/fmqgeqby/

```
<a class="" href="#popup1">Get a Quote</a>
<div id="popup1" class="myoverlay">
<div class="mypopup">
<h2>REQUEST A PHONE CALL</h2>
<a class="myclose" href="#">×</a>
```

Is there any possible solution for this to close popup, when user click outside of site?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the jsfiddle didn't work so I couldn't see it but can you change it to use bootstrap?  Bootstrap's modal works very well.

If not, you could mimic some of what they're doing with your own code.

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Answer (score 0):

One way to go with is using html labels with hidden checkbox. You will need two labels to be able to toggle the checkbox - one outside of the popup and another inside. Not the cleanest solution, but works:

HTML:

```
<label for="toggle"><a href="">Get a Quote</a></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">

<div id="popup1" class="myoverlay">
  <label for="toggle"></label>
  <div class="mypopup">
    <h2>REQUEST A PHONE CALL</h2>
    <a class="myclose" href="#">×</a>
    <div class="mycontent">
      <p> Hello </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -999em;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #popup1 {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

#popup1 label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

[Full example here](https://jsfiddle.net/fmqgeqby/16/)

Comment: Thanks, Morpheus your logic was awesome.  but isn't fulfilling.  it's not working in wp site.  maybe somewhere it is clashing with contact form elements.

Comment: Is your site published anywhere? If so, you can update your question and we will try to help you out.

Comment: yes sir, its here - http://bagful.com.au/demo/wordpress-websites/#  for popup click on get a quote